# Generate ID on before insert trigger

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with AUTO_INCREMENT of a table so I created a trigger to try to solve the problem

```
CREATE DEFINER=`medplantoes01`@`%` TRIGGER `medplantoes01`.`MEDICO_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `MEDICO` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET NEW.id_medico = (select max(id_medico) + 1 from MEDICO);
END
```

But I'm getting this message when inserting:

> Error Number: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

AUTO_INCREMENT option is unchecked on column ID_MEDICO but even with this option I get the same message.

using MySQL 5.7

PS: sorry for my english :P

Comment: Can you provide the create table statement please?  show create table your_schema.your_table;

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't speak portuguese, but I can decode this...

```
NEW.id_medico = (select max(id_medico) + 1 from MEDICO);
```

This will not work. If two clients attempt insert at the same time, they will get duplicate id. This is a very, very bad idea. Don't do this.

AUTO_INCREMENT is designed to solve this problem. Use it. You say it does not work: explain how.

In English......

Comment: Hi! thanks for your reply.. so I marked ID_MEDICO as AUTO_INCREMENT and in table options the initial value is correct but when I try to insert gives me the message "Error Number: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'" so I don't know whats is wrong or what I can do

Comment: Check your INSERT sql statement. Perhaps you have an ORM or something in your code which mistakenly sets the column to a value of 0 on insertion?